# Calcular propriedade do objeto atual com a propriedade do objeto anterior

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, map

Tenho um array de objetos onde tenho que fazer o calculo da propriedade `open` atual com a propriedade `open` anterior.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5424e.png)
Em teoria seria:

let valorResultado = [0].open - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5424e.png).open

Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.
Alguém já passou por alguma situação parecida?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

No meu entendimento, a solução depende do contexto, quantidade de objetos que devem ser considerados, etc.

Você pode sim usar `arr[0].open - arr[1].open`, mas se o array for maior que 2 começa a ficar inviável.

Uma outra solução seria a utilização do reduce. O [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) como o nome sugere, serve para reduzir o objeto javascript.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    close: 6.092,
    date: new Date(),
    open: 5.1716
  },
  {
    close: 6.092,
    date: new Date(),
    open: 5.1465
  },
]

console.log('arr index', obj[0].open - obj[1].open);
console.log('reduce', obj.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.open - curr.open))
```